# Erro ORA-01461 ao tentar salvar um campo de texto CLOB gerado por um template. O que faço para corrigir isto?

Tags: python, django, oracle11g

Ocorre erro ao tentar salvar um registro na classe Lotemail.

tabela:

```
lotemail
LOTEMAILID            NOT NULL NUMBER(18)    
LOTEMAILCORPO                  CLOB
```

Classe:

```
class Lotemail(models.Model):
    lotemailid             = models.BigIntegerField( primary_key=True)  
    lotemailcorpo          =  models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lotemail'
```

Trecho da Rotina:

lotemail = Lotemail()
lotemail.lotemailcorpo         = content
lotemail.save()

Na rotina acima a variável "content" é uma String, gerada a partir de uma lista de objetos que vai para um template em layout HTML.

O que é estranho que em uma rotina funciona e na outra não.

Verifiquei tamanho de String e a que dá erro o length é menor que ao que dá certo, e o template tem o mesmo charset (do que dá certo e o que dá errado).

Erro:

```
DatabaseError at /procedimentos/previsao/notas/preview

ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/procedimentos/previsao/notas/preview
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:    

ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Exception Location:     /usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get, line 554
Python Executable:  /root/Documentos/desenvolvimento/intranet-master/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
```

**Peço alguma sugestão para ajudar-me a corrigir isto.**

Answer (score 0):

O erro *"ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"* se refere a [algumas restrições](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201) que o tipo `LONG` tem.

Como sugestão, conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14497831/4551469) no SOEN, você pode:

- criar a coluna como sendo `varchar2`, determinando o tamanho de acordo com o máximo de dígitos, ou
- inserir no campo um valor tipo contador com até 20 caracteres.

> - creating a table with a column of varchar2 (20 or any arbitrary length) and
> - inserting into the above table with a row containing more than 20 characters

---

OBS: na própria resposta do *SOEN lincada* existem algumas outras alternativas que talvez até resolvam melhor o seu problema, vale dar uma olhada.